# LEFT JOIN to return only first row

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am making a join with two tables, tab_usuarios (users) and tab_enderecos (address).

tab_usuarios structure:

| id_usuario | nome | usuario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Administrador | admin |
| 2 | Novo Usuário | teste |
| 3 | Joao Silva | jao |

tab_enderecos structure:

| id_endereco | id_usuario | cidade | uf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | cidade | SP |
| 20 | 2 | Lorena | SP |
| 22 | 2 | Lorena | SP |
| 24 | 3 | Campinas | SP |
| 28 | 4 | Lorena | SP |

I have this simple query which brings me the following result:

```
Select
    u.id_usuario,
    u.usuario,
    u.nome,
    e.id_endereco,
    e.cidade,
    e.uf
From
    tab_usuarios u Left Join
    tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
```

| id_usuario | usuario | nome | id_endereco | cidade | uf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | Administrador | 2 | cidade | SP |
| 2 | user 2 | Novo Usuário | 22 | Lorena | SP |
| 2 | user 2 | Novo Usuário | 20 | Lorena | SP |
| 3 | jao | Joao Silva | 24 | Campinas | SP |
| 4 | teste | fabio | 28 | Lorena | SP |

What I want is, for example, for id_usuario = 2, I only want to bring the id_endereco = 20, which is the first address that have been inserted on the database.

I tried with min and a couple others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: Which version of Myql? 8.0.14 and later have a lateral join that can make this much easier. The other option is a windowing function.

Comment: "... id_endereco = 20, which is the first address that have been inserted on the database..." -- how do you know it's the **first** one? The question does not make sense as asked. Voting to close.

Comment: because id_endereco is primary key with auto increment so the first is the min number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, assuming you have MySql 8.0 and not some ancient 5.x version:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT  u.id_usuario, u.usuario, u.nome, e.id_endereco, e.cidade, e.uf,
        row_number() over (partition by u.id_usuario order by e.id_endereco) rn
    FROM tab_usuarios u 
    LEFT JOIN tab_enderecos e On u.id_usuario = e.id_usuario
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c506baf8157f82390bb335d074e7614c